# is it possible to interpret the semantics output?

Tags: interpreter, compiler-construction

Hi i know this is too dumb to ask.

I have learned in Principles of Compiler Design by Ulman et.al and on the net that interpreter is different from compiler.
the phases of compiler are
lexical->parser->semantics->(then)intermediate code generator. But my instructor in Compiler Design course insisted to us that we design a compiler by having the following phases:
lexical->parser->semantics->interpreter. is this possible?
interpreting the output of semantics? did i miss some topics about designing the compiler?
Thank you very much

Comment: He is asking you to design an interpretive system instead of one of that generates machine code,

Comment: hi @EJP thanks for responding. may i ask what is the interpretive system?

Comment: Basically designing your own virtual machine that is capable of reading the input file and interpreting its content. You can generate 3AC, write it into the file and make your interpreter to read the contents of its file.

Comment: Most interpreters are actually designed that way. The only difference between a language meant to be compiled to interpreter vs one that is meant to be compiled to machine language is that a lot of interpreted language compile down to a semantics that's very hard to compile to machine language.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you studied Ullman, I assume that you are experimenting with a smallish imperative language. The first few phases of any language translation task, interpretation or compilation, is always the same: tokenize the input stream (lexing), build a syntax tree (parsing) then do some semantic analysis.

When you do lexing you have an error if you encounter a character which is not permitted in your language's character set. Think of a language defined over the ASCII alphabet with a non-ASCII UTF-8 char in it.

Similarly when you do parsing you have an error if you are unable to build a correct tree according to your language's rules (ie syntactic error). An example would be a statement

```
if = 5;
```

Looks like an assignment, but in most languages 'if' is a reserved word...so when the parser sees the token for 'if' it decides it wants to see an 'if/else' statement, not an equal sign.

Suppose you finished parsing. Now you know that you have a syntactically correct program. However, this may not be semantically correct according to your languages defined semantics. For example:

```
int x = 3;
float x = 3.1415;
```

would result in a (conflicting types) error in C. The program is syntactically correct (valid with respect to a context-free grammar) but semantically isn't. The role of the 'semantics checks' is to weed out such programs, so you can define your translation from the semantically correct syntax tree to the target machine (interpreter or code generator) *without* having to think of semantically incorrect inputs. In other words, semantic checks throw away a few programs you don't want to translate, because it may be ambiguous or whatever. The semantics phase only adds information (ie decorates) the syntax tree.

Once you know that your input program in its decorated syntax tree form is correct with respect to your language syntax and semantics, you can do whatever you like: compile it (translate) to machine code (or an abstract machine or byte code) or interpret it. It is possible to interpret a syntax tree but it is usually easier to interpret a flat representation of it, like three address code.

Executive answer: yes, your instructor wants you to interpret the result of the parser enriched with semantic information.

Answer (score 0):

"semantic" is a word with theoretical (university) sense, "to interpret" is more "practical" and hard to strict compare both, or both have common meaning (partially) (disclaimer: my personal, unformal understanding)

From real world: one of my implementation (ANTLR) has AST as "intermediate code" (btw no generator phase) and fragments of code by every tree element (semantic rules) execute action (interpretation) by TreeWalker.

Note of real programmer: lexing and parsing are more formal and from many years can be implemented by automats. Semantics cannot be formalised at similar level, need be done "by hand" (with only partially support from automats)

Example 
`p r i n t` (get letters from input stream and build atom `'print'`) is task of lexer, analyse `print` in wider context does parser. But how to formally describe "on runtime must print your arguments to output"? That is semantic, for me near to interpretation, but words are from different point of view.

EDIT: generation of code sometimes is totally absent in translators.

In different situations: final "interpreter" can be computer CPU (compile to native code, no VM concept), we don't build CPU. We build "semantically correct" code (in sense: correctly implementing goals, in quasi code for 1960' machines: open channel 'n' for output and perform print) for pre-existing interpreter.

Sorry, I'm not theoretic and my English is poor too.

Comment: Subscript: 1960/80 machines are good for my example, opening output was simple assembler operation, not call to library. Please understand my example in this way